# Android 4.4 : Unable to call Java method from Java script

Tags: android, android-webview, android-jsinterface

I am trying to make a call a method in my activity from java script using

```
<button onclick="window.interface.callFromJS()">Call Java</button>
```

This works fine on 4.1.2 JB, but not working on 4.4 Kitkat,

Any idea, how to solve this?

Comment: Target version of app may be set to API 16 only

Comment: If the target version of the application is set to 17 or higher you need to add annotation @JavascriptInterface above each method you want to export to the web view.

Comment: @AjayThakur: Please post this as an answer, so that I can accept it.